# sending array of integers via shared memory

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, producer-consumer

I've written a producer and consumer code wherein a character sequence written to shared memory from producer.c is read from consumer.c
But the problem occured when I tried to send integer array from producer.c via shared memory and read from consumer.c

producer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
int main(){
const int SIZE = 4096;
const char *Obj = "Shm";
int shm_fd;
void *ptr;
shm_fd = shm_open(Obj, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
{
     printf("Map failed\n");
     return -1;
}
                
fgets(ptr, SIZE, stdin);
printf("Producer: Writing the sequence to the shared-memory object is done! \n");
return 0;
}
```

consumer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    const char *Obj = "Shm";
    int shm_fd;
    void *ptr;
    shm_fd = shm_open(Obj, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    if (shm_fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Shared memory failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Map failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Consumer: The output sequence is: %d", (int *)ptr);
    if (shm_unlink(Obj) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error removing the shared memory object %s\n", Obj);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no coordination between the producer and consumer. The consumer can read the shared memory before the producer has written to it.

Comment: I run producer first and consumer later

Comment: For the name of the shared memory, the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) specifies that the name must be "/....".

Comment: The printf() in the consumer must be "printf(".....%s\n", (char *)ptr);". Why to you want to print integers ?